# Qu'as-vous à tant pleurer ?

Tags: conjugaison, paroles-de-chanson

On traite de la chanson folklorique québécoise « Vive l'amour » dans [ce livre](https://books.google.ca/books?id=EM3WAuZI54gC&pg=PA16), p. 16.

La chanson (sous une forme légèrement différente de celle recueillie pour le livre) est aussi [interprétée par le Vent du Nord](https://youtu.be/St7MoZyho4c?t=2m3s). Or c'est vers 2;05 qu'on chante :

> Qu'avez-vous donc, la belle ?        *Vive l'amour*
>   
> **/kavuz/** à tant pleurer ?                  *Pis vivons là, la liberté*

Je constate que paroles telles qu'on les transcrit dans le livre ont bien le « Qu'avez-vous » auquel on s'attend ici ...

Lorsque je transcrivais cette strophe dans un document Word, j'avais choisi « Qu'a-vous » et le logiciel m'a suggéré d'accepter soit « avez » soit « as » :

[image: Qu'as-vous]

Y a-t-il quelque chose qui m'échappe ? « Vous as » c'est une ancienne forme québécoise ou quoi ? S'agit-il d'une sorte de combinaison des deux 2<sup>e</sup> personnes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be in Late Middle French and Classical French a (mainly spoken) contraction of the enclitic *-vous* with its host verb, essentially replacing the 2nd person plural suffix /e/ par /u/:

> Avez-vous > Avous
>
> Savez-vous > Savous
>
> Allez-vous > Allous

For example, this citation from a letter of Marguerite de Navarre, sister to the French King Francis the first (1492-1549):

> Mais **qu'avous** fait voyant ma repentance ? Tost avez mis fin à ma pénitence !
>
> (But what did you do upon seeing my repentance? Soon you put an end to my penance!)

This had disappeared in French (but I've found more modern mentions for other Oil languages) by the time of the standardization of the language, except as a colloquial or regional variant, and those in turn disappeared once subject-verb inversion stopped being used in the spoken language.

However, I've found some mentions of the persistence of this usage in 20th Century Canadian French in the "[Glossaire du Parler Français au Canada](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf)", which sadly doesn't go much further on the vivacity of this usage, or its geographic spread in the Americas.

> "Av'ous vu mon petit garcon?" (p. 82)
>
> "Sa'vous où il est?" (p. 614)

The clip from the question is most likely an example of this usage, but with the information at my disposal, I can't determine whether it's still alive within the idiolect of the singer or an archaism passed along a traditional song.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful scholarship. After I give the question some time to percolate / have more eyes on it, I'll accept this answer in the absence of any competing theories.

Comment: And Word is (as so often) simply way off with its second suggestion, right?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It very much is.